Driver-agnostic creation of temporary table?
Our utility primarily works with SQL Servers, but may be aimed at other server-types some day.
Many of the self-tests use temporary tables, and would currently work only with SQL Server (and Sybase), because the temp-tables are created with CREATE TABLE #NAME...
I'm wondering, if there is a driver-agnostic way of creating temporary tables using JDBC, or whether we'd need to implement (some semblance of) it ourselves...
